# Routing with express.js - Cannot GET Error

Tags: http, node.js, routes, express

Working with `express.js` for the first time, and I am stuck on adding my first route.

My route is defined in `app.js` like so:

```
app.get('/user/:id/photos', function(req,res){
    res.send('user' + req.params.id);
});
```

However curling to `http://localhost:3000/user/1/photos`  just results in a "cannot GET" error.

The index file that was included with express seems to work just fine though.

This is my express `app.js` file:

```
var express = require('express'),
     routes = require('./routes');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration
app.configure(function() {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function() {
    app.use(express.errorHandler({
        dumpExceptions: true,
        showStack: true
    }));
});

app.configure('production', function() {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/test', routes.test);
app.get('/user/:id/photos', function(req, res) {
    res.send('user' + req.params.id);
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

Comment: Please post your express configuration code too, there is nothing wrong with your route definition.

Comment: Ok posted my app.js file also note only routes.index is working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try changing the routes from most specific to least specific.  Routes are matched in order.  If it matches on the `'/'` route first, it will pass to `routes.index`, and never get a chance to router to the `/user/:id/photos` function.

So, instead of:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
....
app.get('/user/:id/photos', function(req,res){
```

Try:

```
app.get('/user/:id/photos', function(req,res){
....
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

As a side note, I think `/user/photos/:id` seems better but I tried out `/something/:id/somethingelse` in my app, and it worked fine.

Comment: I reinstalled node and express and it seems to work fine now. My routes weren't following this convention though so added this as correct answer

Comment: Your explanation does not make any sense! Depending on the route, express will call the corresponding associated handler, i.e. the order in this case does not matter; the order only matters when you are dealing with middlewares. Another thing: `/user/photos/:id` is logically different from what the OP wanted to achieve, i.e. getting the photos of a certain user with a certain ID, and not getting a specific photo with a certain ID from the photos of all users, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks fine. It works for me (express 2.5.8, node 0.6.11). Actually, while bryanmac is correct that order matters, a request for `/user/1/photos` won't match the route `/` - it would for other routes, e.g. `/*`, but not `/` (or `/test` for that matter).

What version of express, node do you run? Also, can you post your routes.js too?

Comment: The order matters in this case? No!

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly this issue. When you want use the route with these  code block, you should change

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/test', routes.test);
```

To

```
app.use('/', routes.index);
app.use('/test', routes.test);
```