# How to get rid of .html extension when serving webpages with node.js?

Tags: html, node.js

I am a beginner with node.js and am using express with the ejs layout, and I want to know how to get rid of the .html extension when putting up a page. For example if I go to my localhost:3000/about.html - that works but I want it to show up as just /about. Also, having trouble figuring out how to change the favicon if anyone knows how to quickly change that from the express default.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry, and I am still confused as how to change the index page.

Comment: You need to set your application's routing, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474951/routing-with-express-js

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I figured it out. I looked at this post  [Render basic HTML view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view-in-node-js-express) which solved the problem I was having.

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);    

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render("index.html");
});
```

And this all goes in the app.js or whatever file you are running.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can also remove the .html in your code above as well.

Comment: You need to have the .html, at least when I took it away it did not load for me and it errored.

Comment: This will work OK but it doesn't scale well when you have a lot of pages. A better approach is therefore to use the express.static middleware (see my answer above).

Answer (score 37):

(I realise this question is old, but it appears high in Google search results, and the accepted answer isn't the best solution.)

The best solution for serving up static content in **express.js** is **express.static**. To avoid having to specify file extensions in URLs you can configure it with a list of default file extensions that it will use when searching for static files:

```
app.use(express.static(pathToBaseFolderOfStaticContent, {
    extensions: ['html', 'htm'],
    ... // Other options here
}));
```

This will serve up *pathToBaseFolderOfStaticContent/somePage.html* or *pathToBaseFolderOfStaticContent/somePage.htm* in response to a GET request to http://www.example.com/somePage, which is what you want. For example, if you visit https://arcade.ly/star-castle, the file it serves up is just a static file called *star-castle.html*. I haven't had to add any special routing for this, or any other static file - it's all just handled by **express.static**.

I only need to add specific routes for content that requires active work on the server to return. A big advantage here is that I can use a CDN to cache more of my content (or nginx if I were running an internal line of business app), thus reducing load on my server.

You can obviously configure as many default file extensions as you like, although I'd tend to keep the list short. I only use it for resources where the URL is likely to appear in the address bar, which generally means HTML files, although not always.

Have a look at the following documentation on serving static content with express.js:

- http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
- http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html (the **express.static** documentation is at the top)

This is also answered at [In express what is the common way to associate a default file extension with static content requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987590/in-express-what-is-the-common-way-to-associate-a-default-file-extension-with-sta).

The *favicon.ico* issue can be solved by dropping your favicon into the root folder from which you serve static content, as well as implementing +Costa's solution where you reference it using a `<link>` in the `<head>` of your documents.

In theory you shouldn't need to do put the favicon in the root folder but, in practice, some browsers will still ask for it from the site root even though it's referenced in the `<head>` of your document. This leads to a spurious 404 error that you'll be able to see in client side debugging tools (e.g., Chrome dev tools).

Comment: how would the js script work if my http server is configured on default port 80? My understanding is that i need to run express `app.listen` on port 80 like `app.listen(80)` but is that possible to run that node application as non-root user? or is there another way?

Comment: or is reverse proxy the only solution?

Comment: Hi @Annjawn - I run as a service to allow my app to listen on ports 80 and 443. I wrote a post to describe the setup on Ubuntu: https://arcade.ly/blog/2017/01/21/running-a-nodejs-app-as-a-service-on-ubuntu/. Hope that helps.

Comment: Of course, the reality is this is still running as root. You may find the following on Server Fault helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux. It describes how to do port redirection, so you could redirect port 80 traffic to port 8080, where you can listen without being root.

Comment: OK understood. My dev server is restrictive so I don't have root access to run express on port 80, so I selected a higher port. But then I faced `allow-access-control-origin` issues even though it's the same application server. I guess it is because of the difference in port number. But that was rather simple to solve from within the Node application using CORS.

Answer (score -1):

The Favicon issue is usually a caching problem. As long as you have this code in your base html layout:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
```

Then just navigate to wherever that image is with your browser, and that should force your cache to update.

Comment: I would highly recommend the express.js videos here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eD2I0zAjM5g Huge, huge, huge help to me after I got my feet plenty wet and needed to get a good serious grasp of the framework.

Comment: Yeah, the favicon was fixed by removing it from the cache.