# url parsing in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to learn express.js on my node server and I try to duplicate this same thing from the http module into express framework.

further explanation:
 I was using the first code before I started using express in which I have a filetree in a "site" folder with webpages such as

```
e:
|_node.js
   |_node_modules
   |_site
   | |_abc
   | | |_123.html
   | | |_456.html
   | | |_789.html
   | |_cde
   | | |_123.html
   | | |_456.html
   | | |_789.html
   | |_abc.html
   | |_cde.html
   |_server.js
```

and I normally access them in the url just by having localhost:8080/abc/123 to get /site/abc/123.html.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = 8080;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = "./site" + q.pathname + ".html";
  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    }  
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(port);
console.log('Running on port ' + port);
```

here, I tried doing this

```
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8080;
var site = "/site"

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = site + q.pathname + ".html";
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    }  
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.sendFile(filename, { root: __dirname + site } );
    return res.end();
  });
})

var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Running on port ' + port);
})
```

but now with the express framework when I type localhost:8080/abc/123 but it only returns 404 Not Found
upon typing http://localhost:8080/abc

apparently the error contains

```
{[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'e:\site\abc.html']
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'e:\\site\\abc.html'}
```

the full path should be

e:\node.js\site\abc.html

and the server.js is located in
e:\node.js

why does it jumps back at e: than at e:\node.js

right now I'm guessing the "root: __dirname" is causing the error, what should i replace it with so that it would start at e:/node.js rather than e:?

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what exactly you're expecting and what is not working? It's not clear what the actual question is.

Comment: updated my question, sorry for that.

 I was using the first code before I started using express in which I have a filetree with webpages such as /abc/123.html, /cbe/234.html and I normally access them in the url just by having localhost:8080/abc/123 to get /abc/123.html. but now with the express framework when I type localhost:8080/abc/123 it returns Cannot GET /abc/123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the only problem but one thing is that

```js
app.get('/', ...
```

will only match the root url, so it'll match `localhost:8080/` but not `localhost:8080/foo` or any other path.

`app.get` [accepts a string, path pattern or regular expression](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method).

To match *anything* you would need to do:

```js
app.get('/*', ...
```

or if you wanted to match only paths that start with a certain segment, you could do:

```js
app.get('/some-path/*', ...
```

and that would match `localhost:8080/some-path/`, `localhost:8080/some-path/foo`, `localhost:8080/some-path/bar` etc.

**Edit:**

With regards to why you're getting the wrong file path, if you look carefully you'll see that **you're only using `__dirname` when you are trying to send the file, but not when you're reading it!**

so you have:

```
var filename = site + q.pathname + ".html";
    // This is not reading from the correct path -
    // it's missing __dirname!
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
```

which should probably change to

```
var filename = __dirname + site + q.pathname + ".html";
    // This is now using __dirname which should be the
    // the directory of your server module
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
```

Then further down you do not need to use `sendFile` since you already have the `data` in a variable, you could use similar code to your example:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write(data);
return res.end();
```

Comment: I tried using ```app.get('*', ... ``` but I only get 404 Not Found

Comment: So that means it goes through to your parser? You should be able to debug your view by printing out the `err` variable to start with, then figure out why it can't find the desired files.

Comment: apparently the error contains
```
{[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'e:\site\abc.html']
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'e:\\site\\abc.html'}```
the full path should be
e:\node.js\site\abc.html

and the server.js is located in e:\node.js

why does it jumps back at e: than at e:\node.js

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should generally check what line your error is on, you're assuming it's raised on `res.sendFile(filename, { root: __dirname + site } ` but it's probably raised by `fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {`

Comment: This totally helped me. I stitched up some results from the searches i made and ended up using the path module, but your solution looks a hell lot cleaner and neat than what I had. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
var site = "/site"
```

to:

```
var site = "site"
```

The root options only applies to relative file names, but a path starting with '/' is absolute to the root of the file system.

Unless you need to do something more to the files, if you're only serving them, probably is better to serve them with express.static() that can be configured to not expose the .html extensions, as answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37990843/2106611

Comment: thank you, but right now I am trying to figure out why the code works on http module and not on express. but for sure this will be handy in the future

Comment: I have edited the answer, with an attempt to address the specific question