# Not able to run simple nodejs server using express with ajax call at client side

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I am trying to create simple NodeJS server using express framework.
and at client site, I wanted to fetch data using ajax call but it's not working

My Server side code

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

   function sendJson(req, res){
       console.log('User connected');
       var jsonEx = '{ "result" :{"name" : "sachin", "surname" : "Tendulkar"}}';
       res.type('application/json');
       res.send(JSON.stringify(jsonEx));
   }

app.use("/",express.static(__dirname));
app.get("/",sendJson);

app.listen(3000);
```

And client side code : which is the file index.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Make ajax call to fetch data
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(resp){
                console.log(resp);
                console.log("Hello");
            }
        });
    });
```

but nothing happens after running the example.
console shows no data.
I enter below url in browser to run this

```
http://localhost:3000/index.html
```

what is problem with the code ?

Thank you,
Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express's app.use and app.get will act the same if you specify a path, but will resolve in order. So in this case, all your requests are rendering the index page. See this post([Routing with express.js - Cannot GET Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474951/routing-with-express-js)) Try changing the json data to another route like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       //Make ajax call to fetch data
       $.ajax({
           url: "http://localhost:3000/data",
           type: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(resp){
                console.log(resp);
                console.log("Hello");
            }
       });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
</html>
```

and

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

function sendJson(req, res){
   console.log('User connected');
   var jsonEx = '{ "result" :{"name" : "sachin", "surname" : "Tendulkar"}}';
   res.type('application/json');
   res.send(JSON.stringify(jsonEx));
}

app.use("/",express.static(__dirname));

app.get("/data",sendJson);  // defining data as the get endpoint instead of root

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Hi @Yousef, Just one question for urls 'localhost:3000/ and 'localhost:3000/index.html', I am getting JSON output.
My question is JSON output configured on '/data' so why it's coming on url 'localhost:3000/'

Comment: @SachinDoiphode, the JSON is outputting in the console b/c we render the html document on '/' but it makes an ajaz call to '/data'. Perhaps, I'm not understanding your question, would you mind re-phrasing?